# Missing methods and cmdlets from NetTCPIP module

Tags: powershell

Currently learning Powershell and I'm trying to figure out why I'm not obtaining the same screens as my tutorial. I'm using NetTCPIP module as an example as more than that module seems to be "missing".

Essentially, the tutorial uses the following line:

`get-command -name *IP*`

The tutorial will show a plethora of cmdlets and functions from various modules. They seem to be on Windows 8.1.

In my case, I see a handfull of methods, none from the `NetTCPIP` for instance. Why is that? I'm on `Windows 7`, with `.Net 4.5` with `Powershell 4`:

PS U:> $PSVersionTable

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

I'm assuming I've simply not installed all the necessary things, or that it's a limitation of Windows 7.

I was following [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx):

Comment: Note that on the documentation page there is no way to select Windows 7.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826123(v=wps.630).aspx.  Also the thread at http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/19559.aspx indicates that NetTCPIP is not available on Windows 7.  Also see http://superuser.com/questions/510249/how-do-you-install-the-nettcpip-from-powershell-3-0-in-windows-7-0...

Comment: Ah, so essentially, could be Windows 8+ related libraries... gotcha. Thanks. Feel free to specify an answer and I'll set it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the NetTCPIP module at [Net TCP/IP Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826123(v=wps.630).aspx) specifies that is only present on Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, and later.

There are also several references in various forums that confirm this.  A couple of them:

- http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/19559.aspx
- https://superuser.com/questions/510249/how-do-you-install-the-nettcpip-from-powershell-3-0-in-windows-7-0